# Intel Galileo GPIO not working from Clanton terminal

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, intel, intel-galileo

I am trying to use GPIO in Intel Galileo Gen 2 using Clanton terminal. For this I am using [this tutorial.](http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergey-s-blog/intelgalileo-programminggpiofromlinux)
I am trying to use GPIO pin 12 of Galileo board. So, according to GPIO Pins Assignment table of this tutorial, I have to `export "38"`. 
For testing purpose, I have connected an led with 330 ohm resistor in series with pin 12 of Galileo board and then I type following command:-

```
echo -n "38" > /sys/class/gpio/export

echo -n "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/direction

echo -n "strong" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/drive

echo -n "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value
```

After these command, I was expecting to get my led ON but nothing happens. So, I check the Pin state using this command:-

```
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio38/value
```

And I am getting `value 1`. So, I want to know what exactly I am missing here. Do pin mapping is different or there is any other way to use GPIO in Clanton? Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you have the diode reversed?  Maybe the LED is active when `0` is output; what did you connect to on the other end? Try toggling the output from `1` to `0` while measuring the pin with a voltmeter.

Comment: Just side note. It's better to use meta-acpi layer where you can easily describe some devices: https://github.com/westeri/meta-acpi/

Comment: That tutorial for Gen **1**, you need one for second generation, i.e. https://emutex.com/educational/71-getting-started-with-intel-galileo-gen-2

Comment: 0andriy :- Thanks bro, it's working now